# SonarQube with Jenkins

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am trying to do sonar analysis using Jenkins. I have the maven based project and using the sonar plugin jenkin's in the post build action. Even the build status is successful but there are few errors in the log like:

```
[ERROR] [17:30:53.200] Class not found: aQute.bnd.annotation.ConsumerType
```

These Jar's are 3rd party libraries and not sure why it is looking for its .class file.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sanjiv

Comment: Can you please add a longer excerpt of the log? (for instance on pastebin.org) Otherwise it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: Thanks Fabrice. In log not much information is available. This is the error which I can see:

Comment: Thanks Fabrice. In log not much information is available. This is the error which I can see:<br>[INFO] [15:54:30.209] Java Main Files AST scan...
[INFO] [15:54:30.215] 36 source files to be analyzed
[ERROR] [15:54:30.881] Class not found: aQute.bnd.annotation.ConsumerType
[ERROR] [15:54:37.611] Class not found: com.day.cq.security.Authorizable
[INFO] [15:54:39.645] Java Main Files AST scan done: 9436 ms

Answer (score 0):

This error is bad logging level set in the sonar java analyzer as this is rather a harmless warning.
This was fixed in version 3.11 of the plugin : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1519

What it reveals is that the bytecode of your external dependencies was not properly provided to the analyzer and that some rules may have more false negatives.

You should provide the bytecode to the analysis to have more precise results using `sonar.java.binaries` and `sonar.java.libraries` properties.

Comment: Is it possible to suppress these warnings?

Comment: This was improved recently thanks to https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2135